# How can I trace error on iPhone when the error doesn't appear in the emulator? Titanium Mobile

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have basic buttons that work in the emulator just fine, but not on the physical phone. I have been told that I should use the Organizer and look at the console, but this only seems to show crash logs. How can I trace an errors on the phone when they do not appear at all in the emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should look at the debug console in xcode, not the organizer.

open up your applications xcode project file and run the app in xcode; will display the errors for you.

the project file is in the build/iphone directory